# Automatically reattach network device in systemd-nspawn

Tags: systemd

I run a systemd-nspawn container with an attached USB network card (Huawei LTE stick presenting itself as a network device) via `--network-interface`. This works fine.

However sometimes the USB network card dies and needs to be physically removed and reattached. In this case the network device is re-created but stays with the host ("unmanaged" in networkctl) and is not automatically moved to the container.

My current solution is to restart the whole container using a udev rule, which is suboptimal.

I have read about `JoinsNamespaceOf` but haven't been able to get it working. Anyone here that can help?